# What is the derivative on $\theta_i$ given the function $CE$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Given a function $CE=-\sum_i y_i log(\hat{y}_i)$ and $\hat{y}_i=\frac{e^{\theta_i}}{\sum_j e^{\theta_j}}$, where $y$ and $\theta$ are vectors. The question asks to compute $\frac{\partial CE}{\partial \theta}$.

(Hint from the original question: $y$ is the one-hot label vector, you might want to consider the fact many elements of $y$ are zeros, and assume that only the $k$-th dimension of $y$ is one.)

*My solution:* $$\frac{\partial CE(y,\hat{y})}{\partial \theta_i}= -\sum_i y_i \frac{1}{\hat{y}_i} \frac{e^{\theta_i}\sum_j e^{\theta_i} -e^{2\theta_i}}{(\sum_j e^{\theta_j})^2}= -\sum_i y_i \frac{\sum_j e^{\theta_j}}{e^{\theta_i}} \frac{e^{\theta_i}\sum_j e^{\theta_j} -e^{2\theta_i}}{(\sum_j e^{\theta_j})^2}=\sum_i y_i (\hat{y}_i-y_i)$$

thus,
  $\frac{\partial CE(y,\hat{y})}{\partial \theta_i}$=\begin{cases}
               \hat{y}_i-1, \quad i=k\\
               0, \quad \text{otherwise}
            \end{cases}

*Solution given:*

$\frac{\partial CE(y,\hat{y})}{\partial \theta}=\hat{y}-y$

or equivalently,
  $\frac{\partial CE(y,\hat{y})}{\partial \theta_i}$=\begin{cases}
               \hat{y}_i-1, \quad i=k\\
               \hat{y}_i, \quad \text{otherwise}
            \end{cases}

The difference shows on calculations of **otherwise**, did I miss anything in my solution?

**Update (Solved):**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial CE(y,\hat{y})}{\partial \theta_k}
    &= \sum_i \frac{\partial CE(y,\hat{y})}{\partial \hat{y}_i} \frac{\partial \hat{y}_i}{\partial \theta_k}\\
    &= -y_k \frac{1}{\hat{y}_k} \frac{\partial \hat{y}_k}{\partial \theta_k}- \sum_{i,i \neq k} y_i \frac{1}{\hat{y}_i} \frac{\partial \hat{y}_i}{\partial \theta_k}\\
    &= - y_k \frac{\sum_k e^{\theta_k}}{e^{\theta_k}} \frac{e^{\theta_k}\sum_j e^{\theta_j} -e^{2\theta_k}}{(\sum_j e^{\theta_j})^2}+\sum_{i,i\neq k}y_i \frac{\sum_j e^{\theta_j}}{e^{\theta_i}} \frac{e^{\theta_i} e^{\theta_k}}{(\sum_j e^{\theta_j})^2}\\
    &=-y_k(1-\hat{y}_k)+ \sum_{i,i\neq k}y_i \hat{y}_k\\
    &= -y_k + \hat{y}_k\sum_i y_i\\
    &= \hat{y_k}-y_k
\end{align*}